# Log4net adonetappender not working in .net 5

Tags: .net, .net-core, log4net, log4net-appender

In a .net 5 worker service project, I have configured the log4net. All other appenders working fine except adonetappender.

There is no error which is occurring and if I see the list of appenders in the log manager repositories, ADO net appender is present. still its not logging to the db. I have used below code in the Configure Services method to configure the log4net.

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
    var dirname = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}{1}", dirname, @"log4net.config")));
});
```

Comment: Same. ASP.NET Core .Net 5 project logging to db is working. in a another project not, with analog settings, it's not working to db, but its working to write to output or to file. do you find a solution to this issue?